# Java Hibernate Configuration Console Error : <Reading schema error: Could not parse ~

Tags: java, hibernate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwxvE.png)
hello, developers
Attempting to connect to hibernate However, the same error as the image occurs.
ClassPath and Driver settings are fine.

In source code connects well but parsing fails on console

[Versions]
MariaDB : 10.11.2-MariaDB
Hibernate : 5.5.7-Final

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duOnr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v19qF.png)

following images is my hibernate configuration console settings

```
public class takeSession {
        public Session sessionTake() {
            
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        
        List<loadBean> table = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM peak_load", loadBean.class).list();
        
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<loadBean> crit = builder.createQuery(loadBean.class);
        Root<loadBean> root = crit.from(loadBean.class);
        crit.select(root);
        
        Query<loadBean> sql = session.createQuery(crit);
        List<loadBean> results = sql.getResultList();
                
        for(loadBean bean : results) {
            System.out.println(bean.getLoad());
        }
        
        return session;
    }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            takeSession sess = new takeSession();
            Session take = sess.sessionTake();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please share your source code as the plain text format